# Send multiple instructions with one transaction @solana/spl-token

Tags: javascript, node.js, solana-web3js

I have a question how can i send multiple instruction with only one transaction with @solana/spl-token ?

Because i have see with @solana/web3.js i can do transaction().add(...) but not with spl-token im block with the "connection" argument

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
manualTransaction
.add(
  SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: fromKeypair.publicKey,
    toPubkey: toKeypair.publicKey,
    lamports: 0.1 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
  })
)
.add(
  SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: fromKeypair.publicKey,
    toPubkey: toKeypair.publicKey,
    lamports: 1 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
  })
);
```

This will allow you to send multiple instructions at once which will give you an output like in the below image

[image: output]

alternatively, you can do it by creating messages which also acts as a transaction instruction and later populate with

```
    Transaction.populate(messages, [
     fromPublicKey.publicKey.toString(),
   ])
```